# Install and run Ubuntu within a microSD Card?

Tags: system-installation, sd-card, micro-sd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 into my 64GB microSD card.
The microSD is plugged in with an adapter and it's not locked, not even while inserting it.

It all went fine but i get a strange error when i try to run simple commands too:
`sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/username/1: Read-only file system`

This happens after a while that I'm logged in, so it's something that occurs when I'm using the system.

I fixed the errors on the filesystem with `fsck` but after i rebooted my system, it happened again and again.

**UPDATE**
I tried using a normal 16GB SD card, without any kind of adapter.
But with this one, I cannot even complete the installation:
When it comes to installing grub, it will crash with a fatal error message

**UPDATE**
Searching on google, it seems it can be something related to `systemctl suspend`, in fact i noticed this to happen when i resume the system.
I will try installing Mint 19.1 to see if this is a bug from Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @Nmath right now I cannot remember them, but i pressed (y) a lot of times. Now my pc won't boot anymore. I should reinstall it again. And im on my laptop, not a desktop

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wearing the card out with too  many writes to a block.  Search this site for optimize usb, the same optimizations apply to the micro sd card. Basically, the approach is to turn off (mostly) unnecessary writes to directories with noatime on the mount, then move as much as possible to ram (like /tmp, /var/log, your browser cache, etc.)

---

If the adapter shows up in the boot menu, it should be OK. Not all computers will even try to boot off an sd card. In that case, putting it in a USB reader may allow a boot from an allowed device.

Comment: I will do a clean install again, and I will try for this optimization. Could it be the adapter also? Should I try without it?

Comment: I tried using a normal SD card, without any adapter. In the bios is recognized as "Multiple Card Reader". But when I try to install ubuntu, it will completely crash. It's a 16GB SD card with 80mb/s writing speed